# Match everything not in tag <div>

Tags: regex, perl

I need regex that will match *everything* not in `<div>` tag. For example:

`foobar<p>lol</p><div>something</div>blahblah`

Should match `foobar<p>lol</p>` and `blahblah`

Comment: May I have the honour? [Thou shalt not try to parse HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an XML parser instead, like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for Python.

Comment: [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) is a good choice in Perl land.

Answer (score 3):

As Mat and maenu pointed out already, using regexps to parse HTML is –to say the least– error prone. Since you tagged your question with the perl tag, I'll give you a small example using [`HTML::TokeParser::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple), which I think is a good choice for these kinds of manipulation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new( *DATA );

my $is_in_div;
while ( my $token = $parser->get_token ) {
    if ( $token->is_start_tag( 'div' ) ) {
        $is_in_div++;
        next;
    }
    if ( $token->is_end_tag( 'div' ) ) {
        $is_in_div--;
        next;
    }
    print $token->as_is if not $is_in_div;
}   

__DATA__
foobar<p>lol</p><div>something</div>blahblah
foobar<p>lol</p><div>more stuff<div>something</div></div>blahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, and a *big* caveat that this won't work on all HTML (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)), but the following might do the trick:

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $html = 'foobar<p>lol</p><div>something</div>blahblah';

my @fragments = split(m{<div\b[^>]*>.*?</div>}is, $html);
say foreach @fragments;
```

see [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

[Select](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) `*:not(div)`.

Comment: Regular expressions don't use CSS selectors.

Comment: Even if they did, that would find everything that **is not** a div, and the question is looking for everything that **is not inside** a div.

Comment: — so **1** that isn't what the question is asking for, **2** a selector is useless without a selector engine and you don't even bother to suggest one that could be used, and **3** that selector would be insufficient anyway.